# PHP execute Python doesn't working

Tags: php, python, ubuntu

I have a Python script and an index.php file in the var/www/html/mac folder. I want to execute the Python script in php with this code:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('sudo python /var/www/html/mac/script.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

But it doesn't work. What can I do?

OS: Ubuntu

Comment: Does the PHP script have permission to `sudo`?

Comment: And also you have to take care that the `python` executable is in the process' PATH environment variable, if you do _not_ specify an absolute path to it.

Comment: Yes, I added the permission but it doesn't work